# Twilio WebRTC client to receive incoming call

Tags: twilio

The question is: is it possible to initiate incoming call to the browser with clientID directly with `POST/Accounts/[AccountSid]/Calls` API (or in any other way except the one described below)?

The documentations says yes, but when I provide the `clientId` like that: `{ "to": "the_user_id" }`, I'm getting a very confusing and weird error:

```
{
"code": 21215,
"message": "Account not authorized to call +843873743. Perhaps you need to enable some international permissions: https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/calls/geo-permissions/low-risk"
}
```

I have no clue what is that `+843873743` number. It seems like internally twilio tries to call it instead of my clientId value I provided.

It works fine, if I provide real phone number (like `+1821...` etc) - `{ "to": "+1821..." }`. It makes call as expected, it follows instructions under WebHook url I provide.

I also works, if in the TwiML I provide the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Calling WebRTC client</Say>
    <Dial callerId="+38312312312312">
        <Client>the_user_id</Client>
    </Dial>
    <Say>Bye</Say>
</Response>
```

But the solution above requires that I have to call a real phone first, and then to add a WebRTC client to the conversation. I want to call the WebRTC client first, and then add any other person using TwiML just as usual.

What I do is I'm playing with [twilio quickstart js example](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/client-quickstart-js).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There's really not enough code here to go on.

Comment: It's not about code. I've shown request params I'm using here, API endpoint I'm using here... I assume that's enough. The code is just about calling that API with the given params. I also used curl to do the same request, and it results with the same output. So it's not about code (I'll probably remove ruby tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've missed the important part of documentation, that can be found [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls#specify-the-calls-recipient).

What I basically have missed is that when you're calling a WebRTC client, you should prefix the clientID with `client:` - so the correct request is:

```
{
  "from": "+1-202-555-0112",
  "to": "client:the_user_id",
  "url": "https://your-server.com/twilio_ml/webhook.xml"
}
```

So it works like a charm.

Comment: Glad you got this sorted. The number "+843873743" in this case comes from the T9 numerical version of the letters you used (8 = t, 4 = h, 3 = e... until you spell "theuserid").